# MySQL - how to make the table antisymmetric

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table:

```
f1 | f2
---+----
a  | b
b  | a
b  | c
```

Expected result:

```
f1 | f2
---+----
a  | b
b  | c
```

OR

```
f1 | f2
---+----
b  | a
b  | c
```

If (a, b) is selected then (b, a) should not be selected

Comment: How about more than 3 rows samples?

Comment: Do you need to do a SELECT with this kind of result or create a constraint for the data in the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `distinct` or `group by` with the `least()` and `greatest()` functions.  Such as:

```
select distinct least(f1, f2) as f1, greatest(f1, f2) as f2
from table t;
```

If you have a passion for ensuring that the pairs are actually in the original table (so (c, b) could not be selected -- although it would not be for the examples you give), then you can do:

```
select f1, f2
from table t
where f1 < f2 or
      not exists (select 1 from table t2 where t2.f1 = t.f2 and t2.f1 = t.f1);
```